# How do I use the same SSH configuration for root and a normal user?

Tags: ssh, permissions, configuration, root

This is a special case of [an existing question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272496/how-to-have-the-same-configuration-for-both-root-and-user).

I have a SSH configuration in `~/.ssh/config`. I update it every time I install a new computer on my network, since I have a number of host-specific configurations. I'd like for the root user to use the same configuration, but I haven't found a good way to set this up.

One possibility was to have an "Include" statement in `/root/.ssh/config` which includes `~/.ssh/config`. This is a technique that I use with other programs. However, this is prevented by the SSH software:

```
$ sudo cat /root/.ssh/config
Include /home/joe/.ssh/config
$ sudo ssh myhost.local
Bad owner or permissions on /home/joe/.ssh/config
```

Making a hard or symbolic link is also forbidden:

```
$ sudo ln -f ~joe/.ssh/config /root/.ssh/config
$ sudo ssh myhost.local
Bad owner or permissions on /root/.ssh/config
```

So I just settled on making a copy:

```
$ sudo rm /root/.ssh/config
$ sudo cp ~joe/.ssh/config /root/.ssh/config
$ sudo ssh myhost.local
Warning: Permanently added 'myhost.local' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
...
```

But then I forget to do this when I update the configuration, and then my backups start breaking because the backup script runs rsync/ssh as root, and so on.

Is there a better way to share my ssh configuration with root?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/etc/ssh/config` for those configurations. It is a system wide ssh client config file and will be read by both root and your user (along with all other users in the system).

Note that `~/.ssh/config` takes precedence over `/etc/ssh/config`. So you will have to remove the common configs shared by root and your user from `~root/.ssh/config` and `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 1):

The systemwide ssh config path is `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` [for Ubuntu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ssh_config.5.html). For me it worked out.